# Create a matrix from a text file - python

Tags: python, matrix

I would like to create a matrix from a three column file.
I am sure it's something extremely easy, but I just do not understand how it needs to be done. Please be gentle, I am a beginner to python.
Thank you

The format of my input file

```
A A 5 
A B 4 
A C 3 
B B 2 
B C 1 
C C 0
```

Desired output - complete matrix

```
  A B C
A 5 4 3
B 4 2 1
C 3 1 0
```

Or - half matrix

```
  A B C
A 5 4 3
B   2 1
C     0
```

I tried this, but as I said, I am VERY new to python and programming.

```
import numpy as np

for line in file('test').readlines():
    name1, name2, value = line.strip().split('\t')

a = np.matrix([[name1], [name2], [value]])
print a
```

WORKING SCRIPT - One of my friend also helped me, so if anyone if interested in a simpler script, here it is. It's not the most efficient, but works perfectly.

```
data = {}
names = set([])

for line in file('test').readlines():
    name1, name2, value = line.strip().split('\t')
    data[(name1, name2)] = value
    names.update([name1])

names = sorted(list(names))
print  names
print data

output = open('out.txt', 'w')

output.write("\t%s\n" % ("\t".join(names)))
for nameA in names:
    output.write("%s" % nameA)
    for nameB in names:
        key = (nameA, nameB)
        if key in data:
            output.write("\t%s" % data[(nameA, nameB)]) 
        else:
            output.write("\t")  
    output.write("\n")


output.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried reading in file contents at least? Can you show some code? Idea would be that you read in the file contents, without the special characters (see `strip()`). You can retrieve individual values from there by spliting each line with `split(" ")`. After that it depends if you want a numpy matrix, or are you satisfied by using nested lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw = []
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        raw.append(line.split())
data = pd.DataFrame(raw,columns = ['row','column','value'])
data_ind = data.set_index(['row','column']).unstack('column')
np.array(data_ind.values,dtype=float))
```

Output:

`array([[  5.,   4.,   3.],
       [ nan,   2.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,   0.]])`

Comment: thank you so much! It does exactly what I asked for! Have a nice day!

Comment: It is worth the time digging a bit into pandas. Look at the dataframe after set_index and unstack. For me it is very usefull. E.g. Analysis of microtiterplates

Answer (score 3):

Although there's already an accepted answer, it uses pandas. A relatively generic way of getting the same effect but by not using a additional library is this: (numpy is used because OP specified numpy, however you can achieve the same thing with lists)

```
import string
import numpy as np

up = string.ascii_uppercase
uppercase = list()
for letter in up:
    uppercase.append(letter)

file = open("a.txt")

matrix = np.zeros((3, 3))

for line in file.readlines():
    tmp = line.strip()
    tmp = tmp.split(" ")
    idx = uppercase.index(tmp[0])
    idy = uppercase.index(tmp[1])
    matrix[idx, idy] = tmp[2]
```

Idea is that you gather all the alphabetical letters, hopefully OP will limit themselves to just the English alphabet without special chars (šđćžčę°e etc...).

We create a list of from the alphabet so that we can use the `index` method to retrieve the index value. I.e. `uppercase.index("A")` is `0`. We can use these indices to fill in our array.

Read in file line by line, strip extra characters, split by space to get:

```
['A', 'A', '5']
['A', 'B', '4']
```

This is now the actual working part:

```
    idx = uppercase.index(tmp[0])
    idy = uppercase.index(tmp[1])
    matrix[idx, idy] = tmp[2]
```

I.e. for letter "A", `idx` evaluates to `0` and so does `idy`. Then `matrix[0,0]` becomes the value `tmp[2]` which is `4`. Following the same logic for "B" we get `matrix[0,1]=5`. And so on.

A more generalized case would be to declare `matrix = np.zeros((3, 3))` as `matrix = np.zeros((26, 26))` because there are 26 letters in english alphabet and the OP doesn't have to just use "ABC", but could potentially use the entire range A-Z.

Example output for upper program would be:

```
>>> matrix
array([[ 5.,  4.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

You just need to make proper adjustment.

hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, my problem is to make the proper adjustment. I am new to python, sorry if my question is very basic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're matrix seems to resember an adjacency matrix of a graph.

I find the answer with pandas much more concise and elegant.
Here's my attempt without adding pandas as an additional dependency.

```
<!-- language: python -->
f = open('.txt', 'r');

EdgeKey = namedtuple("EdgeKey", ["src", "dst"])

g = dict()
for line in f:

    elems = line.split(' ');
    key = EdgeKey(src=elems[0], dst=elems[1])
    g[key] = elems[2]
    key_rev = EdgeKey(src=elems[1], dst=elems[0]) # g[A, B] == g[B, A]
    g[key_rev] = elems[2]

vertices = set()
for src, dst in g.keys():
    vertices.add(src)
    vertices.add(dst)

vertices = list(vertices)
vertices.sort()

# create adjacency matrix
mat  = np.zeros((len(vertices), len(vertices)))
for s, src in enumerate(vertices):
    for d, dst in enumerate(vertices):
        e = EdgeKey(src=src, dst=dst)
        if e in g:
            mat[s, d] = int(g[e])

# print adjacency matrix
print ' ' , ' '.join(vertices) # print header
for i, row in enumerate(mat):
    print vertices[i], ' '.join([str(int(c)) for c in row.tolist()])
```