# Create a list of lists / matrices from a text file in Python 3.4

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I need to create a set of matrices from the file below, the lines/rows with the same value of Z will go in a matrix together.

Below is a shortened version of my txt file:

```
X  Y    Z
-1 10   0
1  20   5
2  15   10
2  50   10
2  90   10
3  15   11
4  50   11
5  90   11
6  13   14
7  50   14
8  70   14
8  95   14
8  75   14
```

So for example my first matrix will be

```
 [-1, 10, 0],
```

my second one will be

```
[1, 20, 5],
```

my third will be

```
([2, 15, 10],
 [2, 50, 10],
 [2, 90, 10]) etc
```

I've looked at a few questions related to this but nothing seems to be quite right.

I started by making each column an array. I was thinking a for loop might work well. So far I have

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
header1 = f.readline()
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    x = columns[0]
    y = columns[1]
    z = columns[2]
i = line in f
z.old = line(i-1,4)
i=1
for line in f:
    f.readline(i)
    if z(0) == [i,3]:
       line(i) = matrix[i,:]
    else z(0) != [i,3]:
         store line(i) as M
         continue
    i = i+1
```

however, I'm getting 'invalid syntax' for line,

```
else z(0) != line(4):
```

By this else clause, I mean that `if z(0)/(z initial) is not equal to line(4)` then this line will then get stored as the first line of the next matrix we will check under this code.

However, I'm not sure how well this would work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `else` means _in all other cases_. So you don't have a condition next to else. What you maybe want is: `elif`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a matrix from a text file - python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165819/create-a-matrix-from-a-text-file-python)

Comment: What exactly is `z` ? a function ? a object ? a list ? ..... You have many syntax errors

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. z is one of the numbers from the list Z. Uh oh..

Comment: Could you include the rest of your code as well?
Also there seems to be several syntax-errors in your code. It is a bit hard to help you when the code does not even run

Comment: @Metareven I have edited the post with the rest of my code. Any help to sort out the syntax would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for your data, it assumes the columns in your text file are tab delimited:

```
import csv
import operator

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    headers = next(csv_input)
    row_number = 1

    for k, g in itertools.groupby(csv_input, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
        row = []
        for entry in g:
            entry = [float(e) for e in entry]
            row.append([row_number] + entry)
            row_number += 1
        print row
```

This would print the following output:

```
[[1, -1, 10, 0]]
[[2, 1, 20, 5]]
[[3, 2, 15, 10], [4, 2, 50, 10], [5, 2, 90, 10]]
[[6, 3, 15, 11]]
[[7, 4, 50, 11]]
[[8, 5, 90, 11]]
[[9, 6, 13, 14]]
[[10, 7, 50, 14]]
[[11, 8, 70, 14], [12, 8, 95, 14], [13, 8, 75, 14]]
```

If your CSV file is exactly as you have it shown, i.e. with spaces separating the columns, then you will need to change the `csv.reader` line as follows:

```
csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: thank you for this! however for some reason my output is only for each line, not all the value with the same z!

Comment: What does your CSV file actually look like? You could try removing `delimiter='\t'`.

Comment: that didnt work either unfortunately! the first column is made up of integers, and the second two columns have numbers that look like this 0.132567E+13. Thank you for all your help already, very useful!

Comment: My question is more, what separates your columns? You could also try: `csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)` if your columns just have spaces between them.

Comment: I have updated the code to use floats which should then work. Change this line `entry = [float(e) for e in entry]`

Answer (score 1):

The following, much simpler code, will do what you want:

```
import numpy as np

# Load the file using numpy (skip the first row which contains the header)
foo = np.loadtxt("/path/to/your/data-file", skiprows=1)

# Prepend a column with the row number
first_col = np.arange(foo.shape[0]) + 1  # +1 because we don't want to start with 0
bar = np.hstack((first_col[:, None], foo))
```

You can now access the single lines via `bar[0], bar[1], ...`

Comment: Just noticed that it is not necessary to edit the file, just tell `loadtxt` to skip the first row.